# Window callback onMenuOpened and onPanelClosed for menu inflated with toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-menu

I'm using view pager in my activity to show some fragments. Each fragment has a separate toolbar with separate menu options.

Implementation:

toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.my_xyz_menu_options);
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this::onMenuOptionsItemSelected);

With single fragment, using the setHasOptionsMenu(true) and creating the menu from function:
onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater)
and setting setSupportActionBar(myToolbar) had helped me taking the call back from activity function onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) and onPanelClosed(int featureId, @NonNull Menu menu)

However, with view-pager setting offset limit to 1 only, is causing an issue with this solution.

Require way to get the callback for onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) and onPanelClosed(int featureId, @NonNull Menu menu) with my toolbar menu

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with those callbacks?

Comment: I'm showing the status progress(something similar to story view in Instagram), so basis on a callback for menu open and close I need to pause and resume the progress respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Used the same implementation as for the single fragment described in the question and following from the fragment on page change:

```
 setSupportActionBar(myToolbar)
```

This however sometimes runs bad by not showing the menu in the fragment at whatever view pager position is scrolled first.